# How do I determine which threads are taking up memory in my iOS app - information from Instruments is limited?

Tags: ios, xcode, cpu-usage, instruments

My application has many different components - an AR view, a separate SceneKit view, UI, and underlying algorithms which are ongoing.

I want to determine which area could be causing performance issues. Here's what Xcode gives me, under CPU:
[image]

These threads all appear to be re-sized so that they fill the height of their graph. So it's not useful to determine what's actually taking up resources.

And here's what Instruments gives me, under Time Profiler:
[image]

Here I can clearly see that some threads dominate, but it's impossible to identify any of these threads.